# Installing packages in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, config, spacemacs

What's the best way to install packages in spacemacs?
1. Using M-x package-install 
2. Include the packages to be installed in dotspacemacs-additional-packages
3. (use-package )

I couldn't find a definite answer anywhere.

Using the package-install to install packages modified the package-selected-packages automatically. Shall I remove all the packages there and include them in dotspacemacs-additional-packages?

I want to keep my .emacs synchronised between my local mac and my home directory in a linux server. So, I was wondering about removing this automatically modified package-selected-packages variable.